# Can the docker image of sonarqube use env for configuring any settings?

Tags: java, docker, ldap, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am trying to configure this [image](https://hub.docker.com/r/library/sonarqube/) with `LDAP`.

In the documentation, they argue you can configure for `jdbc` with :

- `SONARQUBE_JDBC_USERNAME`: `sonar.jdbc.username`***
- `SONARQUBE_JDBC_PASSWORD`: `sonar.jdbc.password`***
- `SONARQUBE_JDBC_URL`: `sonar.jdbc.url`***

I wonder how I could do the same for LDAP.

Is it possible to use any settings through their environment name ?

Eg: `SONAR_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG`

Otherwise, there is inside the container a `/opt/sonarqube/conf/sonar.properties`
is it there and how should I start editing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of achieving what you want is by creating your own sonar.properties file and copying that into the container along with the wrapper.properties.

In the docker-compose.yml

```
volumes:
    - ./sonar-properties:/opt/sonarqube/conf
```

Comment: What would be the best way to handle the passwords and other sensitive data in the sonar-properties file? I don't really want to have it commited in git, I'd rather have the passwords in an environment file/variable.

Comment: @Zaz Hi, after doing some looking around, I imagine you can use docker-compose's "env_file". Some documentation is here https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#envfile

Answer (score 1):

> Otherwise, there is inside the container a /opt/sonarqube/conf/sonar.properties is it there and how should I start editing ?

No, generally what you want to do is possible adding information to your docker-compose file.
In particular in your YML file under the key "enviroment" you can add whatever variable you want.
Here an example of docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"
services:
  registry:
    image: registry:2
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:5000:5000
    environment:
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_FILESYSTEM_ROOTDIRECTORY: /data
      REGISTRY_STORAGE_DELETE_ENABLED: "true"
    volumes:
      - /data/reg:/var/lib/registry
    hostname: "myhost.registry"
```

Than use the compose file to deploy the stack with your custom enviroment.

Comment: Why are you showing a docker `registry` image when I ask about `sonarqube` ?

Comment: No, i showing you a docker service definition using docker-compose to run (for example) a registry.
Sonarqube is a container (like the registry) so i suggest u to create your own compose file to start it with custom enviroment variables.
By the way u can use docker run and add -e VARNAME=value to archive reach the goal

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found it's to take the configuration file (sonar.properties), to parameter it and to place it in docker-compose.yml :

```
services:
  sonarqube:
    image: sonarqube
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
    networks:
      - sonarnet
    environment:
      - sonar.jdbc.url=
    volumes:
      - sonarqube_conf:/opt/sonarqube/conf
      - sonarqube_data:/opt/sonarqube/data
      - sonarqube_extensions:/opt/sonarqube/extensions
      - ./sonar.properties:/opt/sonarqube/conf/sonar.properties
```

With that, the config file localy is placed in docker.

I hope it's help you